# c# identifying scrollbar on control

Tags: c#, winforms

How can I check if a scrollbar is present on a datagridview in Winforms.

Something like (pseudocode)

```
If(datagridview.verticalscrollbar = true)
 do something......
```

Thanks.

Comment: WPF? WinForms? ASP.Net? Silverlight? Which control?

Comment: Hi, it's Winform.  Have edited original post.

Comment: Darren - you have up to _5_ tags to use. Please use more than one.

Comment: @Oded....sorry, didn't realise......will do in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a Datagridview there are special controls for the scrollbars - not like in an usual panel.

You can do sth. like

```
private VScrollBar _verticalScrollBar;
private HScrollBar _horizontalScrollBar;

foreach (Control c in _dataGridView.Controls)
    {
        if (c is VScrollBar)
        {
             _verticalScrollBar = c as VScrollBar;
             if (_horizontalScrollBar!=null)
             {
                 break;
             }
        }
        if (c is HScrollBar)
        {
             _horizontalScrollBar = c as HScrollBar;
             if (_verticalScrollBar != null)
             {
                break;
             }
        }
    }
```

and test if the scrollbar is visible with

```
if(_verticalScrollBar.Visible==true){
//do something you want when scrollbar is visible
}
else
{
//do something when scrollbar is invisible
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There's no property or method specifically for this purpose, but you can tell if the vertical scrollbar is showing by performing the following check:

```
bool scrolling = (dataGridView.DisplayedRowCount(false) != dataGridView.Rows.Count);
```

(It compares the total number of rows with the number currently being displayed; if they don't match, a scrollbar will be visible.)